# How to get all camera clicked images from storage

Tags: android, android-camera

I want all camera  picture from storage. I know that all images are in `DCIM` folder and i will get it from that folder (`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and then folder `dir name` ) but Is there any API or any internal method to give it? because in `DCIM` folder there is also Facebook folder and may others any i think `DCIM` folder name wary with device to device 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any API or any internal method to give it?

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)`

> because in DCIM folder there is also Facebook folder

Individual apps are welcome to create sub-folders within `DIRECTORY_DCIM`. Conversely, there is no requirement for any camera app to store its pictures in `DIRECTORY_DCIM`, or to even store the images as files of any form.

Comment: i want only camera picture dude how can i get is there not any API or method cursor which give it

Comment: @BhanuSharma: No, there is not. `MediaStore` is a general index of files on external storage, including "camera pictures". However, there is no guaranteed means of *only* getting "camera pictures" from `MediaStore` or anything else.

Comment: thnx dude :) i will get all from my method which i made but it contain some logic and device condition so i think if any API or something else if available then... ohk thnx